# How to convert a CLOB type column to LONG type column in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, database, oracle, clob

I need a way to convert a **CLOB** type column to **LONG** type column in Oracle DB without losing data or creating another new table . I am not able to edit types in Oracle SQL Developer
Is there a way with cursors or something ?
Please Help
Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Oracle has deprecated LONG datatype in favour of CLOB for about twenty years now.

Comment: Still i need a solution . Is there a way ?

Comment: The 'why' is important. One of the reasons LONG is deprecated is that it's an extremely awkward datatype to work with. So whether your problem is solvable really depends on what you want to do with the end product.

Comment: I have changed my DB schema , by changing a column type to CLOB from LONG . I did this for testing purpose , Now i want to change it back to long to restore old schema .

Comment: And the teaching is, always take a backup.

Comment: Anyway, you say you cannot create a new table. Can you create a new column on the existing table?

Comment: New column can be done yes

Comment: `LONG` has been deprecated for nearly 20 years now. Do not use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like creating a new column , porting contents of the old column to new column or creating a new table is the only way . 
Thanks all !